# trouble with creating subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-workbench

I am having some trouble with creating a query using subqueries. I have to use subqueries, because it is an assignment from school.

I have two tables, an employee one and a department one. From these tables I have to return the employees that earn more than the average salary of a department.

So this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    ename,
    salary,
    (SELECT 
            department.depname
        FROM
            department
        WHERE
            department.depno = employee.depno) AS depname,
    (SELECT 
            AVG(salary)
        FROM
            employee
        WHERE
            employee.depno IN (SELECT 
                    department.depno
                FROM
                    department)) avgSalary
FROM
    employee
WHERE
    salary > (SELECT 
            AVG(salary)
        FROM
            employee
        WHERE
            employee.depno IN (SELECT 
                    department.depno
                FROM
                    department))
```

this returns:

```
'JONES', '2975.00', 'RESEARCH', '2073.214286'
'BLAKE', '2850.00', 'SALES', '2073.214286'
'CLARK', '2450.00', 'ACCOUNTING', '2073.214286'
'SCOTT', '3000.00', 'RESEARCH', '2073.214286'
'KING', '5000.00', 'ACCOUNTING', '2073.214286'
'FORD', '3000.00', 'RESEARCH', '2073.214286'
```

but the average salary returns the average of ALL the salaries. But I need to do this per department.

I know how to do this by doing the following query:

```
SELECT 
    department.depname,
    (SELECT 
            AVG(salary)
        FROM
            employee
        WHERE
            department.depno = employee.depno) avgSalary
FROM
    department
```

which returns:

```
ACCOUNTING  2916.666667
RESEARCH    2175.000000
SALES       1566.666667
OPERATIONS
```

But I don't know how to combine them or if it is possible without using join.

Any help would be much appreciated

edit:

```
Table: employee
Columns:
empno decimal(4,0) PK 
ename varchar(10) 
efunction varchar(10) 
boss decimal(4,0) 
employed date 
salary decimal(7,2) 
commission decimal(7,2) 
depno decimal(2,0)

Table: department
Columns:
depno decimal(2,0) PK 
depname varchar(14) 
location varchar(13)
```

Comment: can you post just the schema of the tables for... department and employee?  also, does your assignment specify where the subquery needs to be located?

Comment: it sound like you need to add a 'group by' departement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kinda like this...?

```
mysql> select   *
    -> from     employee e
    -> where    e.employee_salary > (
    ->             select   avg(employee_salary) avg
    ->             from     employee ee
    ->             -- this is how you join them without a join...
    ->             where    ee.department_id=e.department_id
    ->          );
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| employee_id | department_id | employee_name | employee_salary |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
|           2 |             1 | employee 2    |              40 |
|           6 |             1 | employee 6    |              50 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

where....

```
mysql> select * from employee;
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| employee_id | department_id | employee_name | employee_salary |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
|           1 |             1 | employee 1    |              20 |
|           2 |             1 | employee 2    |              40 |
|           3 |             1 | employee 3    |              30 |
|           4 |             1 | employee 4    |              30 |
|           5 |             1 | employee 5    |              30 |
|           6 |             1 | employee 6    |              50 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

no joins...

```
mysql> select   e.*,
    ->
    ->          (select  department_name
    ->           from    department d
    ->           where   d.department_id=e.department_id) as department_name,
    ->
    ->          (select   avg(employee_salary) avg
    ->             from     employee ee
    ->             where    ee.department_id=e.department_id) as department_average
    ->
    -> from     employee e
    ->
    -> where    e.employee_salary > (
    ->             select   avg(employee_salary) avg
    ->             from     employee ee
    ->             where    ee.department_id=e.department_id
    ->          );
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| employee_id | department_id | employee_name | employee_salary | department_name | department_average |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
|           2 |             1 | employee 2    |              40 | department 1    | 33.333333333333336 |
|           6 |             1 | employee 6    |              50 | department 1    | 33.333333333333336 |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

you should really avoid joins like that in the select unless really necessary because it's better in real life to just use a join (for efficiency/performance with larger datasets).  the subquery in the `where` is entirely appropriate, though.

Comment: you basically had it on your own already.  you just needed to put everything in the right spot.